# Error In Creating Android Application By Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i created an application on Eclipse and project shows like this :
[image]

and in console error text is:
C:\Users\shforoozan\workspace\MyTestApp\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
C:\Users\shforoozan\workspace\MyTestApp\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

Comment: This Is A Helloword TEst Project Created by Eclipse And I didn't Add Any Think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Help menu, and than install Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

change **style** in *res* folder

**res** >>> **values** >>> **style**  and change theme to **android:Theme.Light**

else, import appcompat-v7 in your app

Answer (score 0):

You should import appcompat-v7 into your app，Theme.AppCompat.Light property is in appcompat-v7
and you can modify the style file in values-v11 andvalues-v14 , just like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>
```